# iOS universal link not working in twitter app, but android app link works

Tags: javascript, ios, web, twitter, frontend

I have make a universal link for my app, it works both on android and iOS by click the link in memorandum。

my ultimate goal is to make it a (deferred )deep link on ads platform(twitter/snapchat/facebook), direct the end user to content in my app if they have it installed or to the app store if not(or stay in a web page)

now it works well in android twitter app, but not working in iOS twitter app;

even if I had my app installed, it can not open my app directly from twitter;

and I have add the app card code, following the https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/app-card

is it a webview limitation by ios twitter ?

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="app">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@{appname}">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{my description}">
<meta name="twitter:app:country" content="SA">
<meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="{appname}">
<meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="{myAppId}">
<meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="{mySchema}">
<meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="{app name}">
<meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="{android id}">
<meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="{android market url}">
<meta property="og:url" content="{url}" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{title}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{description}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{imageUrl}" />
```

Comment: Is it happening just in Twitter App ??

Comment: yeah, just twitter ios